# Save Excel mailmerge to PDF only on the last row with data

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have been using a code which uses mailmerge from the excel sheet to my word template and then proceeds to save all the rows in my excel sheet to PDF(in the word template of course). - The code works perfectly fine.

The code was taken from this forum :

https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

How my Excel sheet looks like :

> A1-E1 = Headers
>   A2-E2 = data
>   A3-E3 = data
>   A4-E4 = data
>   and so on...

**How the code currently works :**
The code saves all rows of data from the excel sheet into my word template(with mailmerge) and then into PDFs.

**My goal :**
I want to change the code so it only saves the last row of data in the excel sheet into my word template(with mailmerge) and then into to PDF.

```
Sub RunMerge()
' Sourced from: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
' Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model to be set, via Tools|References in the VBE.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrMMDoc As String, StrMMPath As String, StrName As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
wdApp.Visible = False
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName
StrMMPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
StrMMDoc = StrMMPath & "MailMergeDocument.doc"
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=StrMMDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
With wdDoc
  With .MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
      "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
    For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("Name")) = "" Then Exit For
        StrName = .DataFields("Name")
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        'Add the name to the footer
        '.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore StrName
        '.SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        .SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
    Next i
    .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
  End With
  .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
```

with:

```
i = .DataSource.RecordCount
```

or, if there are rows in use below that in other columns:

```
i = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
```

where 'A' is any column not containing data below the last record and delete both:

```
If Trim(.DataFields("Name")) = "" Then Exit For
```

and:

```
Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it now shows me an error : "Exit For not within For...Next".
when I delete "Exit For" it shows the following error : "End With without With".
what should I do?

Comment: now it shows me a new error : "Run-time error '4198' and highlights the following line of code : .SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False

Comment: That suggests your worksheet's true last row is empty. Press Ctrl-End and see what row that takes you to.

Comment: my last row is empty because it has a formula in it, is there any way to ignore the empty row that have no actual data in them?
when i removed all the empty rows it worked but then the formulas dont work on new rows anymore.

Comment: nevermind, I got it to work, thanks alot for the help :D

Comment: «my last row is empty because it has a formula in it» Don't keep changing parameters and omitting detail. See updated answer.